# Which directly elected official has received the most votes in a personal capacity?

Tags: voting, international

In America, the president is indirectly elected, even though most voters' ballots would list the candidates by name. In 2016, Trump received [304](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_United_States_presidential_election) electoral votes. In parliamentary systems, the PM still has a constituency, in the most recent UK general election, Boris Johnson received [25,351](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uxbridge_and_South_Ruislip_(UK_Parliament_constituency)#Elections_in_the_2010s) votes personally in Uxbridge and South Ruislip.

**So which directly elected official has had the most votes for them in a personal capacity**, in a free and fair system? The largest number I've found so far is the 2018 Brazilian general election: [57,797,847](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Brazilian_general_election#President) votes for Bolsanaro in run-off voting. I checked out India's president - but they are also elected through an electoral college.

Comment: What is a sufficiently _free and fair_ system? According to the [Democracy Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_Index) the US is not full democracy.

Comment: @raznagul If you want to give a number, let's say a >6.0 on that index

Comment: Why are you only counting votes in the Electoral College for US elections, not actual votes?

Comment: @divibisan Because I'm interested in the quirk that many nationwide offices aren't directly elected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The president and vice president of [Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesia) (democracy index 6.48) are directly elected by popular vote. The current president [Joko Widodo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joko_Widodo) got **85,607,362** votes  in the [2019 election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Indonesian_general_election).